# UITableView with core data pushing incorrect index and data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, filtering, pushviewcontroller

I've been struggling with this for several days already. There are similar problems in this website, but not very the same. And I didn't manage to go forward. I will try to simplify it with one variable.

Problem:
After filtering records in UITableView (records are taken from core data) and trying to push data to another viewcontroller, I get unfiltered index for data, so incorrect data is pushed to new view controller.

My code is below:

I set global variable for core data:

```
var events : [Event] = []

 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if searchField.text == "" {
        filterAdded = false
    } else {
             filterAdded = true
             let request:NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()

            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@ AND nearestDate >= %@", searchField.text!, currentCorrectDate! as CVarArg)

            request.predicate = predicate
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "nearestDate", ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

            do {
                events = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(request)
            }
            catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

            mainListOfDates.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

}

It is triggered every time some character is added to search field. UITableView name is "mainListOfDates".

This function works properly and calculated only filtered events:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return events.count }
```

This function shows all records from core data in UITableView cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
    let event = events[indexPath.row]

cell.eventNameLabel.text = event.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
return cell
```

}

And with "didSelectRowAt" I would like to push filtered or unfiltered (works perfectly with unfiltered) data to new view controller:

```
 let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let eventStoryboard = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EventViewController") as! EventViewController
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

eventStoryboard.getEventName = events[indexPath.row].name ?? "nil"

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(eventStoryboard, animated: false)     }
```

How to solve this issue and send filtered correct data to new view controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you are using the same (data source) array for filtered and unfiltered data the code is supposed to work. By the way dequeueing a cell in `didSelectRow` is pointless.

Comment: You are actually totally right! For simplification purposes I didn't add all the code. However, I found that there was one function that cleared the filter before pushing the results to another view controller. So I moved it after pushing the results to another view controller. Thanks and I hope still that code above will help sobebody.